# Calculating energy function with 1&2-RDM (reduced density matrix) in Qiskit

Tags: qiskit, vqe, chemistry

I am now working on designing quantum error mitigation with variational quantum eigensolvers (VQE). I need  to get the 1&2-RDM from Qiskit, which has already been realized by [Openchemist pakages for Qiskit to get RMDS](http://openqemist.1qbit.com/docs/_modules/openqemist/quantum_solvers/qiskit/qiskit_parametric_solver.html).  The question is how to get the energy function in the following formula (A14) from appendix A of [The Google Hartree Fock paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2004.04174.pdf). I need (A14) to be the objective function for gradient descent, then the VQE algorithm can be implemented.

Because the problem here is to calculate the ground state energy for a quantum chemistry problem, the first step is to extract the molecular information, which is contained in the tensors, h_ij and V_ijkl in (A14). I already got the 1&2-electron integrals by the PySCFDriver. Then, the objective function can be defined for gradient descent. Is there a way to realize the second step in Qiskit?

[image]